# Filter record by using array - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a collection and I want to filter that collection based upon "days_since_last_wallet_transaction" by using an array. For example, I have an array $day = array(2,4,6,8). Now I want to get the record where days_since_last_wallet_transaction is in 2,4,6,8. I think I cannot use "days_since_last_wallet_transaction" in where clause. Here is my query:

```
Customer::select(
                'customers.id',
                'customers.wallet_amount',
                'customers.onesignal_id',
                'customers.phone_number',
                'customers.name',
                DB::raw('DATEDIFF(NOW(), max(wallet_transactions.created_at)) as days_since_last_wallet_transaction')
            )
            ->join('wallet_transactions', function ($join){
                $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'wallet_transactions.customer_id')
                ->where('wallet_transactions.amount', '>', 0);
            })
            ->groupBy('customers.id')
            ->where('customers.wallet_amount', '>', 0);
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: yes, but that is not my question

Comment: Are you able to get days_since_last_wallet_transaction, right

Comment: yes, I am getting

Comment: Ok, what you want means days_since_last_wallet_transaction > 2, greater records or less records

Comment: And you want to compare with array or  single value

Comment: compare with array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204824/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-harris-khan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering below your array:

```
$days = [2,4,6,8];
```

create a raw query as below (Note: you can write this line in query also  )

```
$raw_query = '(DATEDIFF(NOW(), max(wallet_transactions.created_at))) IN  ('.implode(',',$days).')';
```

Your query

```
Customer::select(
                'customers.id',
                'customers.wallet_amount',
                'customers.onesignal_id',
                'customers.phone_number',
                'customers.name',
                DB::raw('DATEDIFF(NOW(), max(wallet_transactions.created_at)) as days_since_last_wallet_transaction')
            )
            ->join('wallet_transactions', function ($join){
                $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'wallet_transactions.customer_id')
                ->where('wallet_transactions.amount', '>', 0);
            })
            ->where('customers.wallet_amount', '>', 0)
            ->havingRaw($raw_query)
            ->groupBy('customers.id');
```

Comment: Use raw query make sql to be vulnerable,  easy cause sql injection.